# Date/String Discrepancy in MySQL Queries

Tags: mysql, string, date, types

I'm noticing some strange behavior in MySQL regarding queries with dates in the WHERE clause. I'm fairly new to MySQL so I'm wondering if this is intended behavior or if there is something I can do to fix this.

The following queries return everything in the table, as if there is no date parameter at all. I get results with dates from 1997 and dates from 2015+.

```
select * from shipments where file_creation_date > 9/12/2014

select * from shipments where file_creation_date > 2014-9-12

select * from shipments where file_creation_date > 2014-09-12
```

The following queries work just fine:

```
 select * from shipments where file_creation_date > '2014-9-12'

 select * from shipments where file_creation_date > '2014-09-12'
```

Notice how the date is formatted as a string. The datatype for that column is DATE and the format is yyyy-mm-dd. You'd expect an actual date to work just fine, but for some reason it only works if I make it a string with the right format.

The database we are using currently accepts dates in pretty much any format, as a date, or as a string and the query works fine. Why is it that MySQL only accepts a very specifically formatted string when the datatype is DATE? Is there something I can do to change this?

Thanks

Comment: All databases that I know accept dates as strings (okay, the one exception is MS Access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first three queries are comparing the date to a calculated numeric value - 9/12/2014 = 0.00037239, 2014-9-12 = 1993 etc. The date is converted to a numeric value in format yyyymmddhhmmss.sss (20141209000000.000) & the two compared.

When entering the date as a string, MySQL does an implicit conversion to the correct datatype and the times compared - giving the expected result.

The answer to the question why does MySQL do this is because that is the way it is designed - in line with standard SQL dates are entered as strings.

If you want to use different time formats then check the MySQL documentation regarding date & time functions : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

NOTE when using functions like STR_TO_DATE then you will need to know the exact format that you are converting from - otherwise you will get null values as the date returned.